# Why IE11 does not support webkit-appearance?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, webkit-appearance

Despite [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn793580(v=vs.85).aspx) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) statements IE11 doesn't seem to support `webkit-appearance` at all. When trying setting `-webkit-appearance` to any of claimed to be supported values (`none`, `button`, `textfield`) to any element it doesn't affect element.

For example this code will work in any browser except IE:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background-color: red;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

I am running Windows 10 Pro x64 if that helps.

#### UPDATE

Edited corresponding section on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) page to reflect [BoltClock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44845375/1548895).

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. What more research effort do you want than links to not one but *two* separate sources? What is unclear about the statement that -webkit-appearance has no effect in IE11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like MSDN and by extension MDN aren't entirely clear on this.

IE11 on the desktop does not support `appearance` in any form. But IE11 *Mobile* does. In fact, [only IE11 Mobile ships with support for the `-webkit-` prefix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn736066.aspx). To be clear, the desktop version does not.

The individual pages on MSDN does not state that this support only applies to Windows Phone 8.1, hence the false impression that it applies to IE11 on the desktop, too.

Both desktop and mobile versions of Microsoft Edge do support the prefix like IE11 Mobile does, however.

Comment: Thanks for the observation. My personal guess is that Microsoft made a row about how mobile websites are working better on Windows Phone after they supported a bunch of webkit APIs. Perhaps they are specifically worried about mobile experience rather than desktop experience. See here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2014/07/31/the-mobile-web-should-just-work-for-everyone/